# Как вывести только назначенные теги на странице?

Tags: php

В примере кода работает вывод назначенного производителя на странице:

```
    <?php if(($this->config->product_show_manufacturer_logo && $this->product->manufacturer_info->manufacturer_logo!="" ) || ($this->config->product_show_manufacturer && $this->product->manufacturer_info->name!="")): ?>
                <div class="zt_manufacturer">
                    <?php if ($this->config->product_show_manufacturer_logo && $this->product->manufacturer_info->manufacturer_logo!=""){?>
                        <div class="manufacturer_logo" style="font-size: 125%; color: #6a6a6a; padding-top: 13px;">
                            <?php print _JSHOP_MANUFACTURER;?>: <span><a href="<?php print SEFLink('index.php?option=com_jshopping&controller=manufacturer&task=view&manufacturer_id='.$this->product->product_manufacturer_id, 2);?>">
                                <img style="width: 105px;" src="<?php print $this->config->image_manufs_live_path."/".$this->product->manufacturer_info->manufacturer_logo?>" alt="<?php print htmlspecialchars($this->product->manufacturer_info->name);?>" title="<?php print htmlspecialchars($this->product->manufacturer_info->name);?>" border="0" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    <?php }?>

                    <?php if ($this->config->product_show_manufacturer && $this->product->manufacturer_info->name!=""){?>
                        <div class="manufacturer_name">
                            <?php print _JSHOP_MANUFACTURER?>: <span><?php print $this->product->manufacturer_info->name?></span>
                        </div>
                    <?php }?>
                </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Имеется код, где выводятся все теги без исключений.

```
<div class="mod_jshop_tags <?php echo $canvas_id; ?>">
<canvas width="200" height="200" id="<?php echo $canvas_id; ?>">
    <?php
        foreach($tags_list as $tag) {
            $link = 'index.php?option=com_jshopping&controller=search&task=result&setsearchdata=1&tag_id=' . $tag->id;
            $href = SEFLink($link, 1);
            $cur_click_per = $tag->click_count * 100 / $max_click_count->max_click_count;
            $cur_font_size = $max_font_size * $cur_click_per / 100;
            if($cur_font_size < $min_font_size) $cur_font_size += $min_font_size;
            $cur_font_size .= 'rem';
            $cur_color = ($cur_font_size == $max_font_size) ? '#ED9710' : '#7F2347';
            echo '<a style="font-size: ' . $cur_font_size . '; color: ' . $cur_color . '" href="' . $href . '">' . $tag->tag_name . '</a>';
        }
    ?>
</canvas>
```

Как в нижнем коде вывести только назначенные теги?

Comment: Что значит назначенные? По идее вам нужно в массив $tags_list загнать те теги которые хотите вывести, а не все как сейчас.

Comment: На примере первого кода, там выводится назначенный производитель товару.

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = 'тут текст';
$tags = '<div><img><span>...'; //теги, которые не нужно удалять
$text = strip_tags($text, $tags_to_delete); //функция strip_tags, первый параметр - текст, второй параметр - список тегов, которые не нужно трогать
```

Comment: Дело в том что для каждой страницы назначены разные теги.

Comment: Как вывести автоматически именно те теги что присвоены странице

Comment: Так у вас есть массив тегов. Можно пройтись по массиву и собрать строку вида '<tag1><tag2>'. Но это будет костыль. Где хранится информация по разрешенным\запрещенным тегам?

Comment: К сожалению не разбираюсь в php.

Comment: <?php 
foreach($tags_list as $key=>$val){
 $link = "index.php?option=com_jshopping&controller=search&task=result&setsearchdata=1&tag_id=". $tags_list[$key]->id;
 $href = SEFLink($link,1);
 $cur_click_per = $tags_list[$key]->click_count * 100 / $max_click_count->max_click_count;
 $cur_font_size = $max_font_size * $cur_click_per / 100;
 if ($cur_font_size < $min_font_size) $cur_font_size += $min_font_size;
 $cur_font_size .= 'em';
?>
 <span><a style="font-size: <?php echo $cur_font_size?>;" href="<?php echo $href;?>"><?php echo $tags_list[$key]->tag_name;?></a></span>
<?php }?>